# mysql select after where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM table_a as a, 
       table_b as b 
 where a.something=0 
       and b.active=1 
       and (select c.AVG(rating) 
              from table_rating as c 
             where c.id=a.id)>=$rating
```

This part doesn't seem to work

```
and (select c.AVG(rating) 
       from table_rating as c 
      where c.id=a.id)>=$rating
```

How can I fix it?

Edit:
the problem was here `select c.AVG(rating)` it should be only `select AVG(rating)`

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: And also explain what "doesn't seem to work" means.  Error message?  Unexpected results?  Crashes your server?

Comment: What is not working? Please give an example.

Comment: It doesn't return any number, thanks everybody I found the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table_a as a, table_b as b 
where a.something=0 and b.active=1 and
 (
   select AVG(c.rating)
   from table_rating as c
   where c.id=a.id
 ) >= $rating
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  No its not.. i have changed c.AVG(rating) to AVG(rating)

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac i have no questions to ask. I pointed out the mistake but no one spotted it :-P . The person who asked the question spoted it :-P

Comment: Un-downvoted, but that change of yours is too hard to spot. Adding some explanation as to what you changed about the query an how that solves the problem would make this a better answer.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac , I'll make sure my future answers are more understandable and directly pointing out the mistake and its correction :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try .. should work // or may be not

SELECT COUNT(*),(select c.AVG(rating) from table_rating as c where c.id=a.id) as rating FROM table_a as a, table_b as b where a.something=0 and b.active=1 and rating>=$rating

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ,AVG(c.rating) 
FROM table_a as a, 
     table_b as b,
     table_rating as c
where a.something=0 
   and b.active=1 
   and c.id=a.id
   and c.id >= $rating
```

better use JOINS here if you have relation between tablea and tableb.

if you provide the relation between table a and table b i can imporove my answer.